# Texlive installation

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, latex

I have been using the default installation of LaTeX(Texlive) which is available in Ubuntu Software Centre. However now I want to install full Texlive. Should I remove the copy of Texlive I already have and then do `sudo apt-get install texlive-full` or just keep it and do `sudo apt-get install texlive-full`? Please provide detailed steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see from Ubuntu Pacakages site http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/texlive-full. This is

> TeX Live: metapackage pulling in all components of TeX Live

Feel free to use command-line tools to examine packages, for example: `apt-cache show texlive-full` gives the following output
http://paste.ubuntu.com/12904879/
As you see this package has all texlive-* packages as dependencies, and it is not conflicts with them but instead depends on them. 
So installing texlive-full will just install addition packages, not touching another packages. It's like a superset.

Comment: But should I remove it and then download the full package?